# Why have my questions not been well-received (danger of being blocked)?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Today I saw this message on SF:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

I don't really understand why. **I was hoping for some specific guidance as to what has been wrong with my previous questions?** I provide a lot of detail and feel like they are good questions but maybe I am missing something.

My past questions: https://serverfault.com/users/289829/imthenachoman?tab=questions

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's good that you've asked here rather than ignoring the warning.

It's an automatic system, based on the "results" of your questions - how many upvotes and downvotes they've gotten, how many have been closed, deleted.

No one except SE developers knows the exact parameters of the system, but it looks to me like you've got some not-terrible-but-not-great questions that have a few downvotes and closures and some not-bad-but-not-great questions that are ok but didn't get much interest - no upvotes, no answers.

So I don't think your questions are that bad, but they aren't getting much positive interest to counter the few that have been closed or downvoted.  I don't have much specific guidance, there are a couple closed questions closed for essentially asking for product recommendations which is off-topic on most or all SE sites.  Also, a couple of them are asking about your setup at home which is off-topic here.  When setting up servers and network for home use, there are often compromises made that wouldn't happen in a business environment, e.g. your latest question asking about TLS configuration when you haven't assigned your system a domain name.

Try to avoid those types of questions and hopefully you'll be able to get a few upvotes and keep going.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful. I always have a hard time with which site to use for which question. I usually post one place and am told to tr SF or SU instead. I appreciate the guidance. It does help.